# Reading Exif data usind CCR.Exif causing access violations

Tags: delphi, jpeg, exif

I have a programme, called ViewPhotos, that gives me problems when reading Exif data.  I am using CCR.Exif (by Chris Rollistone).  CCR.Exif does not reside in the project directory.
To figure out what is happening I created a small programme called TestExif, which consists of a form and a button that invokes the procedure shown below.  I also copied the exact same procedure to ViewPhotos.  TestExif is using the same unit CCR.Exif as ViewPhotos.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ExifData: TExifData;
  ADate: TDateTime;
  OriginalDate: TDateTime;
  Mes: string;
begin
  ExifData := TExifData.Create;
  try
    ExifData.LoadFromGraphic('C:\000\APhotos\ADigital\2017\BlueMountains\PC090131.JPG');
    ADate := ExifData.DateTime;
    Mes := 'Date' + ' = ' + DateToStr(ADate) + #13;
    OriginalDate :=  ExifData.DateTimeOriginal;
    Mes := Mes + 'OriginalDate' + ' = ' + DateToStr(OriginalDate);
  finally
    ExifData.Free;
  end;
  ShowMessage(Mes);
end;
```

Now, I do the following:

1. Build ViewPhotos.
2. Run the Test-Procedure in ViewPhotos. This
   generates an access violation.
3. Close ViewPhotos and open TestExif.
4. Run TestExif.  This generates an access violation.
5. Build TestExif.
6. Run TestExif and get the expected result.
7. Close TestExif and open ViewPhotos.
8. Run ViewPhotos and get the proper result.

How can I find the cause of my problem and rectify it?  What are the steps I should take?

The access violations are:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the debugger to locate which line(s) the AV's are occurring on. If you don't know how, start here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Debugging_Applications, or here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amZIKVk7_-U

Comment: @Dave I know how to use the debugger.  What baffels me is that by buiding one programme I affect the other.  I would like to know how that can happen.

Comment: You find out by debugging

Comment: The text of the AV's would be interesting. The exact address can *sometimes* (but often not) be a hint what could be wrong. Also, take a look at the stack trace. That often shows which line is the culprit.

Comment: @Rudy I have added a copy of the access violations to my question.  The stack trace is a bit out of my reach.  I am a hobby delphi programmer.

Comment: @Rudi: so am I (hobbyist). Easy to read a stack trace: the top one is the last one called, the one below that is the code that called it, the one below that is the code that called that, etc.

Comment: So something is reading a nil. Try to follow that back using the stack trace. Sometimes you get addresses like 0x00000010 or so, and then you know it is trying to read a member (at offset 16) of an object which turns out to be nil, etc.

Comment: FWIW, if such an error message is open, all you have to do is to press Ctrl+C and the text of the dialog (including OK button) will be copied to the clipboard. Just paste that text into your message. No need to take a screenshot and post the pic.

Comment: What is the return result of the `ExifData.LoadFromGraphic`? If it is false it could mean that your program could not open the image file. Also you should probably check `ExifData.Empty` return value to see first if your image even contains a valid EXifData in it before you try reading the data itself. Check the provided examples to see of the proper usage of the said library.

Comment: @Rudy  Thanks for your encourigement!  I found the solution.
Building the programme generating access violations, I had the Syntax option for Complete boolen evaluation set to true.
Building the programme giving the correct output, I had the Syntax option for Complete boolean evaluation set to false.
So!  **For CCR.Exif to compile correctly the Syntax option for Complete boolean evaluation must be set to false.**

Comment: @Rudi: OK, that makes sense. But note that this is false by default and AFAICT hardly anyone (including me) ever checks if this is not the case. ISTM that for the very very few cases it is needed, the complete boolean evaluation could be done explicitly, in code, so the option could be removed from the language altogether (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

For CCR.Exif to compile correctly, the **Syntax option** for **Complete boolean evaluation** must be left **false** (which is the default setting).